# What is the correct initializer for a non-static 2D array?

Tags: c++11, variables, initializer-list, non-static

Visual Studio allows: int a[3][3] = { 0 }; for BOTH local variable and non-static class variable. However, GCC only allows this for local variables, but requires int a[3][3] = { {0} }; for class variable initialization. Is GCC too restrictive or VS to permissive?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class InitArray {
 public:
   InitArray();
   void PrintArray() const;
 private:
   int a[3][3] = { 0 };       // compiles in Visual Studio 2017, but not GCC
                              // modify to = { {0} }; to compile in GCC
InitArray::InitArray() {
   PrintArray();
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
         a[i][j] = 1;
      }
   }
}

void InitArray::PrintArray() const {
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
         cout << a[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
}

int main() {
   InitArray A;
   A.PrintArray();
   int a[3][3] = {0};          // OK in BOTH compilers
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
         cout << a[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: No answer but an advice: Make it right for the platforms you are developing for. So, the question is, what output do you get for using `{{0}}`? And what output do you get for using `{0}` in the local case? Do you have to be platform independant?

Comment: What is the compilation error you get in GCC?

Comment: To Daniel:  When appearing as below GCC issues error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
    int a[3][3] = { 0 };

Comment: To Tobi: {{0}} works on both platforms, so that is the portable code and what I will write going forward. Mostly, the question was a curiosity -- why the difference in what the GCC compiler allows for local vars versus class vars?

Answer (score 1):

You code only internalizes the first cell in the array, Change the line

```
int a[3][3] = {0};
```

to

```
 int a[3][3] = {1};
```

and look a the output, only the first cell will be one and the rest will be zero.

about the compilation question, I'm compiling with GCC and both compile for me. The difference between the types of initialization is that

```
int a[3][3] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Will compile, you will get

```
1 2 3 
4 5 0 
0 0 0
```

But
    int b[3][3] = {{1,2,3,4}};
Will not compile because of

> too many initializers for ‘int [3]’
>   This will happen because {{}} will only initialize the first a[3] array in the a[3][3] matrix. If you want to init all of it you'll need to call it like this:

```
int a[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

Comment: Daniel: Thanks. If I wanted various non-zero values, then I would explicitly provide those. However, in situations where I want zero values, I often init the first item as zero knowing the remainder will then default to zero. Saves typing. Do you know of an instance (compiler) which ONLY initializes with the values provided and does not zero the remainder? If so, I'd change my practice.

Comment: Ah I see, that's a bit confusing because it seems like you want to init the whole array to 0. If you just assume the default is 0 why even have the = {0} at all?. As for you question I think all c++ compilers will init the first value as 0, and then use default for the rest

Comment: My experience with gcc is the following: int a[5]; as global variable is initialized to zeros - int b[5]; as a stack (local) variable is UNINITIALIZED - int c[5] = {1, 2}; follows the partial array initialization rule which initializes the elements as given and fills in the remaining part of the array with zeros.